# worklight rich page editor only lists internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, editor, ibm-mobilefirst

According to the IBM Worklight docs, both IE and Safari are supported on windows if the base Eclipse platform is at 3.7 or greater.  I am currently running eclipse version 3.7.2 with the worklight plugin (5.0.5), I also have tried 5.0.6 using IBM Install Manager in a separate environment.  When I open the primary html file for my worklight project, I only see an option for IE (Internet Explorer) for my Rich Page Editor.  I have Safari for windows and Firefox also installed on my system.  I believe I don't see Firefox because I am using the 64 bit version of eclipse, but I don't see Safari as an option either.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. You will need to use a 32 bit version of Eclipse for the remaining browser buttons to appear in the RPE toolbar. :x